# Google Cloud Build error no project active

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firebase-hosting, google-cloud-build

I am trying to set up Google Cloud Build with a really simple project hosted on firebase, but every time it reaches the deploy stage it tells me:

```
Error: No project active, but project aliases are available.

Step #2: Run firebase use <alias> with one of these options:

ERROR: build step 2 "gcr.io/host-test-xxxxx/firebase" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

I have set the alias to production and my .firebasesrc is:

```
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "host-test-xxxxx",
    "production": "host-test-xxxxx"
  }
```

I have firebase admin and API Keys Admin permissions on my cloud builder service and I also want to encrypt so I have Cloud KMS CryptoKey Decrypter

I do

```
firebase login:ci
```

to generate a token in my terminal and paste this to my .env variable, then generate an alias called production and do

```
firebase use production
```

My yaml is:

```
steps:
# Install
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
  args: ['install']
# Build
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
  args: ['run', 'build']
# Deploy
- name: 'gcr.io/host-test-xxxxx/firebase'
  args: ['deploy']
```

and install and build work fine. What is happening here?

Rerunning firebase init does not seem to help.

Update:

building locally then doing firebase deploy does not help either.

Answer (score 1):

Ok the thing that worked was changing the .firebasesrc file to:

```
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "host-test-xxxxx"
  }
}
```

and

```
firebase use --add
```

and adding an alias called default.